# Qt C++ Rotation Animation

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I am trying to make a rotation animation of a pushbutton rotating. I have tried the following, but it doesn't rotate.

In my .cpp file I have the following:

```
ui->setupUi(this);

animation = new QPropertyAnimation(ui->pushButton, "rotation");
animation->setDuration(10000);
animation->setStartValue(0);
animation->setEndValue(-360);
animation->start();
```

In my .h file I have declared the following:

```
QPropertyAnimation *animation;
```

I have also tried it with a QGraphicsRotation, but same result:

```
rotation = new QGraphicsRotation(ui->pushButton);
rotation->setAngle(-360);
```

Does anyone know why it doesn't work? As basically the same code with a "geometry" in the QPropertyAnimation() animation works?

Answer (score 0):

QPushButton doesn't have "rotation" property ([QWidget properties](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#properties), [QAbstractButton properties](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qabstractbutton.html#properties), [QPushButton properties](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qpushbutton.html#properties)).
You have to create your own [property](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/properties.html) and override paintEvent. Also you need to calculate rectangle of rotated button.

```
class MyButton : public QPushButton
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MyButton(QWidget *parent = nullptr) : QPushButton(parent), _angle(0) {}

    Q_PROPERTY(int rotation READ getAngle WRITE setAngle)

    int getAngle() { return _angle; }
    void setAngle(int angle) {
        _angle = angle;
        repaint();
    }

    virtual QSize   sizeHint() const override {
        // ... calculate new size
    }

    virtual void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event) override {
        Q_UNUSED(event);

        QStylePainter painter(this);
        QStyleOptionButton option;
        initStyleOption(&option);

        QTransform transform;
        transform.translate(width() * 0.5, height() * 0.5);
        transform.rotate(_angle);
        transform.translate(-width() * 0.5, -height() * 0.5);
        painter.setTransform(transform);

        painter.drawControl(QStyle::CE_PushButton, option);
    }

private:
    int _angle;
};
```

Comment: Ok thanks, so which class has the "rotation" property then? In that link not even QWidget has it but I've seen some people use it in some examples online. If I can't use it, why doesn't QGraphicsRotation work?

Comment: @Multiplier I suppose QGraphicsRotation works with QGraphicsItem. By the way I modified my answer. You can see example of rotation. But you need improve it.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I understand your answer partially, but could you explain in more detail the calculating of new size? The size will be the same, just rotated at some angle right? Do you mean with each new angle of rotation (custom pain event), the rectangle has to be custom defined again, with each of the corners moved to the appropriate new points further clockwise/anticlockwise?

Comment: Yes, you need to define new borders for button. But I'm not sure how to do it.